# Jquery hide mega dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, slidetoggle, slideup, navbar

I'm trying to build a mega dropdown navbar. Jquery is not a strong point of mine but I need to use it to achieve what I'm looking for. I'm aware of the various topics on similar questions but none of them did exactly what I'm looking for(Remember I'm not a pro in JQuery and I'm only gonna use it for this smaal piece of my site).

So far I hav this HTML Layout:

```
<div class = "header-wrapper">
            <div class = "header">
                <ul id = "navbar">
                    <li class = "toggle">Navbar Option 1
                        <ul class = "dropdown">
                            <li class = "dropdown-inner">
                                Dropdown 1
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class = "toggle">Navbar Option 2
                        <ul class = "dropdown">
                            <li class = "dropdown-inner test">
                                Dropdown 2
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
                var $dd = $(".dropdown");

                $('.toggle').click(function() {
                    $('.toggle').not(this).children('ul').slideUp("slow");
                    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("slow");

                });

                /* Don't hide the dropdown when clicking inside */
                $dd.on("click", function(evt) {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                });

            } 
            </script>
```

My .dropdown div does show and hide as intended. But what I need is to add a function that hides the dropdown if clicked outside of it. Now I can listen to a click event on the document but then a click on my .toggle Navbar options doesn't work either.

Thus, I want to keep the .toggle link functional and have it so that you can click inside the .dropdown ul without it closing but if you click anywhere else on the page the .dropdown should .slideUp("slow").

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: You can use [jquery event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to check what initiated that event and can work accordingly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery event.target to check what initiated that event and can work accordingly. Something like below

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#navbar").click(function (event) {
        var check = $(event.target).attr('class');
        alert(check);
        if (check == 'toggle') {
            //do something
        }

        if (check == 'dropdown') {
            //do something
        }
    });
});
```

Check out working [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3WEwn/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have however tried it without any success. I don't think however that I would need to change my code entirely as it is currently working exactly like it should with the exception of sliding Up any open dropdowns if not clicked on either .toggle or .dropdown/.dropdown-inner. I believe that it would be possible to do it by just adding a couple of lines of code to my existing code but as said earlier I don't really know Javascript as I usually only use PHP.

Comment: @user1933068 You just need to put same code inside `if` statements... Nothing is changed